# Access Denied: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token. error shows up even if all the permissions were already granted by Admin

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I have checked the related issues for this error message and most of them were resolved by just providing the correct permissions but in my case needed permissions are already provided.

[image]

I'm using the official{?} microsoft graph collections for postman. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections. I am able to follow the instructions alright up to putting the correct client id, secret and tenant id.

With this I'm able to get successfully get the token, but when it comes to get the list of sites, I get the error Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.

I tried to decode the returned token but for some reason, the roles part is not visible anymore in the decoded value. Perhaps it got removed?

Whats frustrating with this is in Azure portal it says that I already have the correct permissions and they have been granted by the admin already but still when I call the function.

I double checked the values that I provided, client id, secret and permissions and the ones in portal azure are the same with the values I placed in postman.

Right now, I'm not sure where to look next.

edit: the admin already provided consent/approval 10 hours ago so this shouldn't be a timing issue that the changes haven't been applied yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use microsoft graph to find the permissions you want and add them, not sharepoint.
[image]

Comment: dang, thanks. I'll just be waiting for the admin's consent so I can test it again